# google maps rectangle fixed height

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to draw a editable and draggable rectangle on my google maps.

The only issue I have is that I cannot find to give a fixed height to the rectangle: only the width may be editable.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/rectangle-event?hl=nl

I think this question asks the same: 
[Google Maps Rectangle editable: how to lock (fixed) height from editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685320/google-maps-rectangle-editable-how-to-lock-fixed-height-from-editing)

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rectangle Events</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
// This example adds a user-editable rectangle to the map.
// When the user changes the bounds of the rectangle,
// an info window pops up displaying the new bounds.

var rectangle;
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0753735,4.3064351),
    zoom: 13
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(52.0619767211195, 4.295717407226562),
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.07294407400174, 4.313404876709001)

  );

  // Define the rectangle and set its editable property to true.
  rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });

  rectangle.setMap(map);

  // Add an event listener on the rectangle.
  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', showNewRect);

  // Define an info window on the map.
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
// Show the new coordinates for the rectangle in an info window.

/** @this {google.maps.Rectangle} */
function showNewRect(event) {
  var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

  var contentString = '<b>Rectangle moved.</b><br>' +
      'New north-east corner: ' + ne.lat() + ', ' + ne.lng() + '<br>' +
      'New south-west corner: ' + sw.lat() + ', ' + sw.lng();

  // Set the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(ne);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why the down vote? I did my research, but I'm about the conclude that it might not even be possible because rectangles work with bounds?

Comment: To quote [Marcelo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo) "Everything is possible, you just have to code it.", you probably can't do it with the native Google Maps Javascript API "editable" rectangles though.

Comment: But what would be the workaround for this? Could you guide me in some direction?

Comment: What does your current code look like? What have you tried?  I know I can figure it out given time, but I don't have time to write your application from scratch.

Comment: I editted the first post

Comment: See my answer to the question [Google Maps Rectangle editable: how to lock (fixed) height from editing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685320/google-maps-rectangle-editable-how-to-lock-fixed-height-from-editing)